# Как поставить балун на гуглокарте?

Tags: google-maps-api, карты, javascript

Есть код:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        /* Создать точку - центр */
        var pntx=12.0659970797;
        var pnty=42.0060243683;
        var center = new GLatLng(<?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['MAP']['VALUE']?>);
        /* Создать основной объект карты */
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("mapgoogle"));
        /* Создать элементы навигации, масштабную линейку */
        var map_ctrl=new GLargeMapControl();
        var map_type_ctrl=new GMapTypeControl();
        var map_scale_ctrl=new GScaleControl();
        /* Добавить элементы навигации */
        map.addControl(map_ctrl);
        /* Кнопки выбора типа карты*/
        map.addControl(map_type_ctrl);
        /* Добавить масштабную линейку */
        map.addControl(map_scale_ctrl);
    map.setCenter(center, 12, G_NORMAL_MAP);
  }
}
</script>
```

Но не пойму как сделать чтобы на карте отмечались координаты красным шариком.

Comment: Вам нужен полупрозрачный кружок, как тут
http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple.html
?

Comment: Как здесь http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Ваш HTML-текст',
    //position: new google.maps.LatLng(userLat, userLong)// Или так, чтобы не привязывать к маркеру
});
infoWnd.open(map, marker);
```

А вообще, [тут](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows) подробнее и красивее описано. 
По Гугломэпам, обычно, мало вопросов из-за нормально написанной документации к ней.

Answer (score 0):

```
var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(0.0000, 0.0000)); //установить маркеру координаты
map.addOverlay(marker); //добавить маркер на карту
```

А лучше посмотреть [этот](http://www.mapbuilder.net/Map.Code.Demo.php) код